# Excel VBA macro to filter a tab based on results of a COUNTIFS formula

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, formula

I am working with a tool which looks at the workload of our team. One tab has an overview of all the types of tasks we work on, while we have a separate tab for each specific process (let's call them task 1,2,3 etc.)

One of the things the Overview tab does is use formulas to show outstanding work, what hasn't been allocated to anyone yet, what hasn't been completed, and so on. These are countifs formulas (for example, counting how many tasks meet the following: Allocated To: field is not blank, but Date Completed is blank, which will show allocated but incomplete work). This gives us a number, but it becomes a bit manual when going into the specific tab for this Task type and finding which tasks this formula is referring to.

I am trying to add a button with a macro that will essentially take the Countifs formula and use the same logic to filter the tab in question (Task 1,2,3 etc.)

My experience with coding VBA from scratch is minimal so I've not got anything to show, however I was going to go down the route of using conditional formatting with a formula (which would make manually filtering easier), but I wasn't sure how to make a row highlighted based on a formula which looks at a specific cell/column

Comment: Conditional formatting only cares about the value (given by a formula or not) in the cell. Just remember that the CF looks from the top left cell (very first) in the range you select, so make sure your references are correct. As for learning to use VBA: the first steps would be recording what you would do manually and going from there. Over time you'll learn the ropes of doing it from scratch (mostly, our friend google still helps now and again).